# Unable to host the Web API Core 2.1 targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a really basic Web Api which was taken from the .Net Core 2.1 template which targets the .Net framework 4.7.2 It gets executed via the IISExpress and the Project profile as well but when using IIS as the profile, it just stops in debug mode when debugging and when run via the IIS, browse site, it throws 404.

Below is how the Program.cs and startup.cs goes

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)            
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            var networkEnvironmentBasePath = string.Empty;
            switch (env.EnvironmentName)
            {
                case "Development":
                    networkEnvironmentBasePath = "\\\\chaays.amprog.com\\devinet\\Configuration\\";
                    break;
                case "Local":
                    networkEnvironmentBasePath = "C:\\charon.cmiprog.com\\DevInet\\Configuration\\";
                    break;
                case "Test":
                    networkEnvironmentBasePath = "\\\\nays.amprog.com\\testinet\\Configuration\\";
                    break;
                case "UAT":
                    networkEnvironmentBasePath = "\\\\ays.connect-link.com\\UATInet\\Configuration\\";
                    break;
            }

            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", true, true)
                // .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", true, true)
                //.AddJsonFile(networkEnvironmentBasePath + "ApiEndpoints.json", true, true)
                .AddJsonFile("ApiEndpoints.local.json", true, true);
                //.AddJsonFile(networkEnvironmentBasePath + "Kafka.json", false, true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
          logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
          logging.AddConsole();
          logging.AddDebug();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
 //some authentication and swagger code goes here
}
```

In configure method,

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
{
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseMvc();
 app.UseSwagger();
 app.UseSwaggerUI(
         options =>
            {
                // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version
                foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions.OrderByDescending(x => x.ApiVersion).ToList())
                {
                    var name = description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant();
                    if (description.IsDeprecated)
                    {
                        name += " (deprecated)";
                    }
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", name);
                }
            });
```

My web.config is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
 <system.webServer>      
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" stdoutLogEnabled="false">
    <environmentVariables />
  </aspNetCore>
</system.webServer>
</location>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have the launchsettings.json as

```
{
"$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iis": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/AcordRequestProcessingApi",
  "sslPort": 0
},
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53886",
  "sslPort": 0
}
},
"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/Values",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"AcordRequestProcessingApi": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"IIS": {
  "commandName": "IIS",
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
}
}
```

Edit:

FYI, I happen to see this in the stdout info:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
  User profile not available. Using 
'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\AutoGenKeys\S-1-5- 
82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415\DataProtection' as 
key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: E:\Ays\Ticket TrackBy\AcordRequestProcessingApi\solAcordRequestProcessingApi\AcordRequestProcessingApi
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:26695
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/AcordRequestProcessingApi  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST 
http://127.0.0.1:26695/ACORDREQUESTPROCESSINGAPI/iisintegration  0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
Request finished in 157.718ms 202 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
Request finished in 401.6889ms 404 
Application is shutting down...
```

Comment: There is probably something different with the default http headers.  The 404 indicates the server not found but could be the port number or localhost.  You can use cmd.exe >ping localhost to see what the local host is on each machine.  Some cases it is the machine name other it is the loopback 127.0.0.1.  Best way of debugging is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the headers in 1st request on working machine with headers in 1st request on 2nd machine.   Then fix non working app so headers are same as working.

Comment: Let me give a try..

Comment: But I have only one machine. I mean when I run the application in different profiles like IISExpress and Project profile, it successfully executes.

Comment: The profiles are using different defaults for the http header.  You will be able to see differences with the sniffer.